# Dual-Boot Nightmare: Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 in Samsung-NP550 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows, bios

My win-10 OS got infected with malware, even after scanning the malware still was there and affected functionality of my OS. So I decided to take data backup and do clean install. Earlier I had Win-10 with Ubuntu-15.10. So I wanted to dual boot win-10 with, latest Ubuntu-16.04.

So I used rufus with the following setting: Partitioning scheme- MBR portioning scheme for UEFI, File system- NTFS. As earlier when I was trying MBR portioning scheme for BIOS or UEFI-CSM ,then widows was giving error while installing. So I used the the given setting for both OS. When I was installing Windows OS- I formatted all the drives and deleted them, including the window recovery portioning. But this time unlike last time there were two new partitions of Samsung:SAMSUNG_REC. I have no idea what they are for, are they malware or something for recovery. So I left them as it is and installed windows and left a partition empty(this was the last partition). Then I installed Ubuntu-16.04. Ubuntu was working fine but when I tried Windows-10, it was all glitched. In first time every thing got super zoomed and graphics got glitched. After re-starting the resolution got changed and the graphics were still some how glitching. I had dual-boot earlier too but something like this never happened. Is there some problem with disk partitioning? Or is it because of some malware? Or is Ubuntu-16.04 not compatible with Windows-10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not related to malware. 
Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 both can be installed on multi-boot system and they perform well with each other.

It seems you need to install `Drivers` after installing Windows 10. Your system seems Samsung, so find out latest drivers on their [Download Center](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads)

> **[Important Drivers you should get after installing Windows 10.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-to-install-and-update-drivers-in-windows-10/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293)**
>
> When you perform a new install or upgrade, you should download the latest software drivers from the manufacturers website for your computer model. Important drivers include: Chipset, Video, Audio and Network (Ethernet/Wireless). For laptops, make sure you download the latest Touch Pad drivers. There are other drivers you will probably need, but you can often download these through Windows Update after have a working Internet connection setup.

BTW, `Samsung:SAMSUNG_REC` partitions are for recovery, Normally `SAMSUNG_REC` is a recovery software partition, and `SAMSUNG_REC2` is a recovery data partition (factory image, systems softwares).